# Android check if a View has a tag

Tags: java, android, android-view

Is there any way to check if a view has a tag?

I have two views to differentiate from and currently I'm using the tag. I have checked http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html for all methods involving tags and have not found any way to check if a tag exists.

So currently I'm using :

```
if(null == v.getTag(R.string.tagid)){
    // do stuff
}
```

But I try to avoid null checking as far as possible and I'm just wondering if there is a way to check if the view has a tag or if there's a different way to differentiate between two views(I don't have a id to compare to so I can't use the id).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, theres no other way. You will have to check for null conditions. The [`getTag()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()) returns an object which might be null, so yea its best to compare it against null before doing any further manipulation to it.

**UPDATE**
Instead of using string values as ids, its best to use specific ids that are defined in your [ids.xml](https://developer.android.com/samples/ActionBarCompat-Basic/res/values/ids.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Object myObject = tv.getTag();
if (myObject != null) {
}
```